# how to limit the size of the file that exporting from bigquery to gcs?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I Used the python code for exporting data from bigquery to gcs,and then using gsutil to export to s3!But after exporting to gcs ,I noticed the some files are more tha 5 GB,which gsutil cannnot deal?So I want to know the way for limiting the size

Comment: I've filled in a bug report to update the documentation with the relevant information. Something is off here, maybe the internal compression size is at 1GB but when exported flat results 5GB, but this should be confirmed officially https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111569287

Answer (score 2):

So after the issue tracker, the correct way to take this is.

1. Single URI `['gs://[YOUR_BUCKET]/file-name.json']`

> Use a single URI if you want BigQuery to export your data to a single
>   file. The maximum exported data with this method is 1 GB.

Please note that data size is up to a maximum of 1GB, and the 1GB is not for the file size that is exported.

2. Single wildcard `URI ['gs://[YOUR_BUCKET]/file-name-*.json']`

> Use a single wildcard URI if you think your exported data set will be
>   larger than 1 GB. BigQuery shards your data into multiple files based
>   on the provided pattern. Exported files size may vary, and files won't
>   be equally in size.

So again you need to use this method when your data size is above 1 GB, and the resulting files size may vary, and may go beyond the 1 GB, as you mentioned 5GB and 160Mb pair would happen on this method.

3. Multiple wildcard URIs

   `['gs://my-bucket/file-name-1-*.json',
   'gs://my-bucket/file-name-2-*.json',
   'gs://my-bucket/file-name-3-*.json']`

> Use multiple wildcard URIs if you want to partition the export output.
>   You would use this option if you're running a parallel processing job
>   with a service like Hadoop on Google Cloud Platform. Determine how
>   many workers are available to process the job, and create one URI per
>   worker. BigQuery treats each URI location as a partition, and uses
>   parallel processing to shard your data into multiple files in each
>   location.

the same applies here as well, exported file sizes may vary beyond 1 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Try using single wildcard URI

See documentation for  [`Exporting data into one or more files`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files)

> Use a single wildcard URI if you think your exported data will be
> **larger than BigQuery's 1 GB** per file maximum value. BigQuery shards
> your data into multiple files based on the provided pattern. If you
> use a wildcard in a URI component other than the file name, be sure
> the path component does not exist before exporting your data.
>
> Property definition:
>
> ['gs://[YOUR_BUCKET]/file-name-*.json']
>
> Creates:
>
> gs://my-bucket/file-name-000000000000.json
> gs://my-bucket/file-name-000000000001.json
> gs://my-bucket/file-name-000000000002.json ...
>
> Property definition:
>
> ['gs://[YOUR_BUCKET]/path-component-*/file-name.json']
>
> Creates:
>
> gs://my-bucket/path-component-000000000000/file-name.json
> gs://my-bucket/path-component-000000000001/file-name.json
> gs://my-bucket/path-component-000000000002/file-name.json

Comment: Hi Mikhail,when I used wildcard  ,gcs would create 14 files,most of them are larger than 5GB..ALSO i used multiple wildcard uri  ,for one pattern ,gcs would create 2 file ,one file 6GB and the other 0B

Comment: i think what is happening is that 1GB is counted based on compressed size in bigquery table. have you tried compression? and btw, do you export CSV or JSON? JSON format is too verbose - might be another reason for big size

Comment: yes ,I exported as json,,from my point of view ,the 1gb may be the data length not including schemas...I afraid that After some file be conpressed ,some of them may also be larger than 5Gb